# Testing ARC Chrome App in virtual ChromeOS

Tags: google-chrome-arc

I'm experiencing a few issues with my APK when I run them through ARC-welder on OSX and so would like to verify whether these also occur in ChromeOS. Until I have a Chromebook is there a way to build and run my app in a Virtual ChromeOS?
I have Parallels and their ChromeOS set up, but the build is very old and I have not found a more recent version.

Or, do I just have to go out and spend some money on a Chromebook?

Thanks for reading

Comment: If the Parallels provided image is old, perhaps you should look into alternatives? A quick search on the internet turned up many articles about running ChromeOS in a virtual machine.